# Ubuntu 22.10 Installer not showing existing partitions

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, 22.10

I have recently downloaded and booted from the live USB of the latest Ubuntu release (22.10).
When I get to the partition screen of the installer it is showing only one entry "/dev/sda", and an option to create a partition table. The existing partitions are not displaying that is I have 3 NTFS partitions, of which 2 are Primary partitions and the other one is a Logical partition, while the remaining space is unallocated.
I am trying to dual boot it with my already existing Windows 11 install. I have an 256 GB SSD.

So, how can I fix this issue? I can't seem to understand why is that happening in this particular release of Ubuntu. Earlier I had Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, and it installed and showed my existing partitions correctly.

Comment: If Windows 11, it should be UEFI with gpt partitioning which does not have logical partitions. Have you updated UEFI firmware & SSD firmware. UEFI fast boot off? Windows fast start up off? Windows bitlocker off? https://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/unable-to-mount-windows-10-partition-it-is-in-an-unsafe-state & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation What brand/model system. Some also need extra settings. Note that Windows updates may turn fast startup back on.

Comment: I have an HP EliteBook 840 G2 laptop which has an 256 GB SSD with an Intel Core i7 5th generation CPU. And I'm using BIOS based settings not UEFI and using an MBR partitioning scheme. Windows fast startup is also switched off, and Bitlocker is also disabled.

Comment: Microsoft has required vendors to install in UEFI/gpt mode since Windows 8. I thought Windows 11 did not install in BIOS mode? BIOS boot should work, but you have to have system set to boot in BIOS/CSM/Legacy mode. UEFI & SSD updates are still required. HP Elitebook 840 G5 gpt issues - 
HP put a fail-safe gpt recovery into the UEFI Settings,  go into the UEFI Menu in Security -> Hard Drive Utilities -> Uncheck "Save/restore GPT System of Hard Drive"
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2436271